# Books like active reading series for German

Tags: book

I had 5 different level of active reading books for English which increased my reading very well. For increasing my reading talent in German:

> **Is there any book (or series of books) for German like active reading to teach us how to read faster.**

For more information about the active reading series visit [ngl.cengage](http://ngl.cengage.com/)

I'm not talking about an online website. I just want a book for reading when I'm not online.

My level: Learned around 2k words. (Not a beginner and not a pro one, too.)

I wanna improve my reading as fast as I can! So what is your suggestion?

Comment: Of course there are books and series for German. You may get better answers if you explain a bit what's special about these active reading books. And is your goal to read faster or to improve your understanding of the language?

Comment: @Robert for more information about active reading series books plz visit http://ngl.cengage.com/ ... my goal is improving my skills of reading better, faster(x word per minute), with better pronunciation...like the books which has CD's to listen...   i already have books for understanding the language...

Comment: Ich vermute, der Fragesteller wünscht sich Material für die https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQ3R-Methode

Comment: genau das ist was ich will @Janka

Comment: Whats wrong with online texts? Can't you just print out the text so you can take notes an take it with you like a book?

Comment: i don't wanna waste my time !  i'm looking for things like this , so when i'm not online  i can learn something new!never stop learning or using ur brain if u wanna successful :) ...  i think this is  one of the best ideas, maybe i'll try ur idea, (print out something) thanks  @0x6d64

Comment: This question could be a better fit for [Language Learning SE](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Isn't this question off topic, as it is more based on opinion than definite answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every schoolbook more or less uses this teaching approach. I suggest reading such books to get the best out of it.